# Flutter Camera plugin takePIcture and startImageStream crash

Tags: flutter, dart, camera, google-mlkit

I am using the Camera plugin in my Flutter app to access the device's camera and capture images. However, every time I try to take a picture, the app crashes. The issue seems to be related to the takePicture, startImageStream, and _controller methods in the Camera plugin. I am not sure how to resolve the problem.
I'm using google ml kit if it has any relations.

Here is the relevant code:

```dart
import 'dart:io';

import 'package:camera/camera.dart';
import 'package:flutter/foundation.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:google_mlkit_commons/google_mlkit_commons.dart';
import 'package:image_gallery_saver/image_gallery_saver.dart';
import 'package:image_picker/image_picker.dart';
import 'package:path_provider/path_provider.dart';

import '../main.dart';

class CameraView extends StatefulWidget {
  // ...
}

class _CameraViewState extends State<CameraView> {
  // ...
  CameraController? _controller;

  // ...
  @override
  void initState() {
    _imagePicker = ImagePicker();

    if (cameras.any(
      (element) =>
          element.lensDirection == widget.initialDirection &&
          element.sensorOrientation == 90,
    )) {
      _cameraIndex = cameras.indexOf(
        cameras.firstWhere((element) =>
            element.lensDirection == widget.initialDirection &&
            element.sensorOrientation == 90),
      );
    } else {
      for (var i = 0; i < cameras.length; i++) {
        if (cameras[i].lensDirection == widget.initialDirection) {
          _cameraIndex = i;
          break;
        }
      }
    }
    _startLiveFeed();
    // if (_cameraIndex != -1) {
    //   _startLiveFeed();
    // }
    // else {
    //   _mode = ScreenMode.gallery;
    // }
    super.initState();
  }

void _startLiveFeed() {
    final camera = cameras[_cameraIndex];
    _controller = CameraController(
      camera,
      ResolutionPreset.high,
      enableAudio: false,
    );
    _controller?.initialize().then((_) {
      if (!mounted) {
        return;
      }
      _controller?.getMinZoomLevel().then((value) {
        zoomLevel = value;
        minZoomLevel = value;
      });
      _controller?.getMaxZoomLevel().then((value) {
        maxZoomLevel = value;
      });
      _controller?.startImageStream(_processCameraImage);
      setState(() {});
    }).catchError((e) {
      print(e);
    });
  }

  Future<void> _captureAndShowImage() async {
    if (!_controller!.value.isInitialized) {
      return;
    }
    final directory = await getTemporaryDirectory();
    final path =
        '${directory.path}/${DateTime.now().millisecondsSinceEpoch}.jpg';

    await _controller!.takePicture().then((_) async {
      final result = await ImageGallerySaver.saveFile(path);
    });
  }

  // ...
}

Future _processCameraImage(CameraImage image) async {
    final WriteBuffer allBytes = WriteBuffer();
    for (final Plane plane in image.planes) {
      allBytes.putUint8List(plane.bytes);
    }
    final bytes = allBytes.done().buffer.asUint8List();

    final Size imageSize =
        Size(image.width.toDouble(), image.height.toDouble());

    final camera = cameras[_cameraIndex];
    final imageRotation =
        InputImageRotationValue.fromRawValue(camera.sensorOrientation);
    if (imageRotation == null) return;

    final inputImageFormat =
        InputImageFormatValue.fromRawValue(image.format.raw);
    if (inputImageFormat == null) return;

    final planeData = image.planes.map(
      (Plane plane) {
        return InputImagePlaneMetadata(
          bytesPerRow: plane.bytesPerRow,
          height: plane.height,
          width: plane.width,
        );
      },
    ).toList();

    final inputImageData = InputImageData(
      size: imageSize,
      imageRotation: imageRotation,
      inputImageFormat: inputImageFormat,
      planeData: planeData,
    );

    final inputImage =
        InputImage.fromBytes(bytes: bytes, inputImageData: inputImageData);

    widget.onImage(inputImage);
  }
```

And here is the error message:

````
E/AndroidRuntime( 3547): Process: com.example.pose_detection_app_v3, PID: 3547
E/AndroidRuntime( 3547): java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: CaptureRequest contains unconfigured Input/Output Surface!
E/AndroidRuntime( 3547):        at android.hardware.camera2.CaptureRequest.convertSurfaceToStreamId(CaptureRequest.java:739)
E/AndroidRuntime( 3547):        at android.hardware.camera2.impl.CameraDeviceImpl.submitCaptureRequest(CameraDeviceImpl.java:1243)
E/AndroidRuntime( 3547):        at android.hardware.camera2.impl.CameraDeviceImpl.capture(CameraDeviceImpl.java:1115)
E/AndroidRuntime( 3547):        at android.hardware.camera2.impl.CameraCaptureSessionImpl.capture(CameraCaptureSessionImpl.java:189)
E/AndroidRuntime( 3547):        at io.flutter.plugins.camera.Camera.takePictureAfterPrecapture(Camera.java:664)
E/AndroidRuntime( 3547):        at io.flutter.plugins.camera.Camera.onConverged(Camera.java:223)
E/AndroidRuntime( 3547):        at io.flutter.plugins.camera.CameraCaptureCallback.handleWaitingFocusState(CameraCaptureCallback.java:150)
E/AndroidRuntime( 3547):        at io.flutter.plugins.camera.CameraCaptureCallback.process(CameraCaptureCallback.java:108)
E/AndroidRuntime( 3547):        at io.flutter.plugins.camera.CameraCaptureCallback.onCaptureProgressed(CameraCaptureCallback.java:161)
E/AndroidRuntime( 3547):        at android.hardware.camera2.impl.CameraCaptureSessionImpl$1.lambda$onCaptureProgressed$2$CameraCaptureSessionImpl$1(CameraCaptureSessionImpl.java:679)
E/AndroidRuntime( 3547):        at android.hardware.camera2.impl.CameraCaptureSessionImpl$1$$ExternalSyntheticLambda5.run(Unknown Source:8)
E/AndroidRuntime( 3547):        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:938)
E/AndroidRuntime( 3547):        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
E/AndroidRuntime( 3547):        at android.os```
````

Comment: Can you run the camera plugin example successfully?

Answer (score 1):

The solution was to stop the stream before taking a picture